# Gram-Schmidt in Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, infinity

EDIT:

After some contemplation I decided to phrase the question better to avoid trivial answers.

Consider a Hilbert space with a basis $\{v_{i}\}$ where $i\in I$ an index set, which could be uncountably infinite.

We define a "Gram-Schmidt for infinite dimension" to consist of a total ordering $\leq$ on the index set $I$ and a set of orthonormal basis $\{b_{i}\}$ where $i\in I$, and the following condition is satisfied: for any $i\in I$, then $b_{i}$ can be written as a finite linear combination of $v_{i}$ and $b_{j}$ where $j<i$.

We define a "Gram-Schmidt for infinite dimension with series allowed" to be just like above, except that $b_{i}$ is allowed to be written as series instead of just finite linear combination.

So the question is, can "Gram-Schmidt for infinite dimension" be done in a general Hilbert space starting with an arbitrary basis $\{v_{i}\}$? What about "Gram-Schmidt for infinite dimension with series allowed"?

Clearly, if $I$ is countable, the answer is trivial. The interesting case is when $I$ is uncountable.

Thank you for your answer.

===========

Original question:

In Real Analysis for Graduate Student (Bass) chapter 19 (Hilbert space) page 188, wrote was "The Gram-Schmidt procedure from linear algebra also works in infinitely many dimensions".

So how exactly would such process get carried out?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, Gram-Schmidt is an *algorithm* when working in finite dimensions. In infinite dimensions it lacks an important property of algorithms: Termination after finitely many steps. However, do you see how we can handwave that restriction away with a limit process for the case of a Hilbert space and a countable Hilbert basis?

---

After your clarification of the question:
For a family $\{\,w_j\mid j\in J\,\}\subseteq V$ we let $\overline{Sp}(\{\,w_j\mid j\in J\,\})$ be the space of all $\sum_{j\in J}c_jw_j$ with at most countably many $c_j\ne 0$ and $\sum \lvert c_jw_j\rvert^2<\infty$.
Define a "partial Gram-Schmidt" as a subset $J\subseteq I$ together with a total order $\le$ on $J$ and orthonormal $\{\,b_j\mid j\in J\,\}$ such that $b_j\in\overline{Sp}(\{v_j\}\cup\{\,b_k\mid k\in J, k<j\,\})$ for all $j\in J$.
Then the set of partial Gram-Schmidts is inductively ordered in an obvious manner, hence ny Zorn's lemma there is a maximal one among them.
I claim that $J=I$ holds for this.
Assume otherwise, i.e. there exists $i\in I\setminus J$.
For $j\in J$ let $c_j=\langle b_j,v_i\rangle$.
If $S$ is any finite subset of $J$ verify that $\sum_{j\in S} c_jb_j$ is the unique vector in $\operatorname{span}(\{\,b_j\mid j\in S\,\})$ that is closest to $v_i$ and that it is shorter than $v_i$. Conclude that at most countably many $c_j$ are nonzero (otherwise one could find finite $S$ that would produce an $\sum_{j\in S} c_jb_j$ longer than $\lVert v_i\rVert$, for example) and that $\sum c_j^2\le \lVert v_i\rVert^2$. Subtract $\sum c_jb_j$ from $v_i$ and normalize to obtain $b_i$ and by letting $i>j$ for all $j\in J$ thus a partial Gram-Schmidt extended to $J\cup \{i\}$, contradicting maximiality of $J$.

Thus for "Gram-Schmidt with series allowed" the answer to your question is "yes" for arbitrary cardinalities.

Comment: I can't see how it can be handwaved using a limit process, but I can see that using countable union. However, it only works for countable basis.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's nice, I'm still not used to use Zorn's lemma. I am trying to expand this technique to the one without series, but it seems like it just can't work. Do you know of any counterexample? However, if I assume that each in $\{v_{i}\}$ is non-orthogonal to only a countable number of them, then the finite linear combination only cases work.

Comment: @Gina Not sure if my exposition is the  best or might have some flaws, but I am afraid as soon as you switch to "ugly" cardinalities you may need some ugly arguments, especially  the Axiom of Choice in some form (here Zorn's lemma). A well-order on $I$ might also do the trick.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I actually don't see how one could get away with just a limit... Could you help me? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since at every step in the Gram Schmidt process you are in a finite dimensional space, there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: Um, I don't get it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Igor, I think you're answering the question "If the index set $I$ is countable, why does Gram Schmidt work", but @Gina's question is about "when $I$ is uncountable", and seems to hinge on whether or not uncountable summation might be useful in a non-separable Hilbert space. Perhaps I misread the question (or didn't understand your answer), but that's why I downvoted. Edit: I see now that you answered the original question, which has since changed.

Comment: @MarkS.:the current question is what I had in mind when I asked the original question; but I have to edit it to clarify because one answer is only about the countable case, and this answer is off-the-mark (it seems like the answerer is thinking that I am worried about each basis needing to be fixed with an infinite sum instead of finite one; but I am actually worried about having an infinite number of basis and thus the process can't finish).