# Is it possible to apply Gram–Schmidt process to orthonormalise a matrix in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, gram-schmidt

Let $V$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{A_{i,j}\}_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ be a matrix of linearly independent vectors of $V$

My question is if is it possible to orthonormalise matrix $A$, getting the matrix $B$ 
such that
$$
\langle B_{i_1,j_1} , B_{i_2,j_2} \rangle = 0
$$
and such that
$$
\forall i \in \mathbb{N}:
\operatorname{Span}(\operatorname{Row}_i(A))=\operatorname{Span}(\operatorname{Row}_i(B))
$$

I have to orthonormalise a matrix and not a sequence so the question is very different from [Gram-Schmidt in Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620667/gram-schmidt-in-hilbert-space) mainly for the second condition. I cannot see no one anything in common. thanks.

Comment: What is the inner product on your Banach space?

Comment: exuse @uniquesolution  me it's a Hilbert space and not Banch space, now i edited, thanks

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620667/gram-schmidt-in-hilbert-space

Comment: thanks @Math1000 now i see