# Proof of Gram-Schmidt for countable sets

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let me first state the theorem.

> **Theorem (Gram–Schmidt Orthogonalisation).**  Let $X$ be an inner product space, and let $S=\{u_1,u_2,\dots\}\subseteq X$ be a countable subset. Define
>           \begin{alignat*}{3}
>         v_1 &= u_1, &   e_1 &= v_1/\|v_1\|,\\
>         v_n &= u_n - \textstyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\langle{e_i},{u_n}\rangle e_i, \qquad & e_n & =v_n/\|v_n\|,
>     \end{alignat*}
>           and for any $n$, if $v_n=0$, then $u_n$ and $v_n$ are discarded, and $u_{n+1}$, $v_{n+1}$ are relabelled to $u_n$, $v_n$ respectively.
>
> Then the set $S' = \{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ is an orthonormal set with $\mathop{\mathrm{span}}S' = \mathop{\mathrm{span}}S$.

The usual proof for when $S$ is finite follows quite straightforwardly by induction on $|S|$. But if $S$ is allowed to be infinite, is the proof still valid?

Comment: Induction for countably infinite cases is quite common, so my instinct is to say yes. Infinite-dimensional vector spaces are indeed a thing.

Comment: @TheCount But wouldn't induction on $|S|$ prove the statement for $|S|\in\mathbb N$, and not $|S|=|\mathbb N|=\aleph$?

Comment: Depending on the situation, sure. Notice that the statement of the theorem does not require $|S|$ finite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding appears to be the following.

You believe that we are inducting on the cardinality of $S$, and therefore are understandably confused about why the statement is true when $S$ is countably infinite.

The error is that we are in fact not inducting on the cardinality of $S$.

There are two inductions here.

The first is in the construction of the map $v:\Bbb{N}_+\to X$, which indexes the orthonormal set.

The second is to prove the following statement
$$\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}\text{, for $i,j\in\Bbb{N}_+$}.$$
Note that $i$ and $j$ are finite in this statement, and we are trying to show that the statement is true for all $i$ and $j$ in the positive natural numbers. Induction is a perfectly valid way to do this.

At no point do we induct on the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: This indeed reflects my intuition, that induction should be possible since we always work with finite subscripts. So if I understand correctly, the statement is by induction on $n\in\mathbb N$, where we then use the map $u(n)=u_n$. Could you possibly provide a bit of a proof outline? The crucial points, none of the inner-product manipulation; just so I make sure I understand the flow of the argument.

Comment: I think I have completed the proof. Could you check if it's correct? See [here](https://i.imgur.com/cf8cGHe.png).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Notice that the statement of the theorem does not say $|S|$ is finite but rather countable. Also, see here:

[Gram-Schmidt in Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620667/gram-schmidt-in-hilbert-space)

For a helpful heuristic: if $|S|$ is countably infinite, we can always find the next element of the orthonormal basis, and so the dimension of any valid $|S|$ is unbounded. Perhaps this requires the Axiom of Choice, but this is widely accepted in my experience.