# Countable orthonormal basis of separable space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, separable-spaces, gram-schmidt

Assume $X$ to be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert-space and $Y\subset X$ to be a not necessarily closed subspace. Then $Y$ is also separable as subspaces of separable metric spaces are always separable. This again means that $Y$ has a countable basis $\left\lbrace y_k:\ k \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace$. Now using Gram-Schmidt (for the infinite dimensional case) we can transform $\left\lbrace y_k:\ k \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace$ into an orthonormal basis $\left\lbrace z_k:\ k \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace$, where orthonormal basis means a set of vectors $z_k$, orthonormal wrt. the inner product on $X$ and such that $\overline{\text{lin}}\left\lbrace z_k:\ k \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace=Y$ and $\overline{\text{lin}}$ denotes the closure of the linear hull.

Is the above reasoning correct, i.e. does any subspace of a separable Hilbert-space have a countable orthonormal basis in this sense? What confuses me is that in general I can find this statement only for $Y$ being a closed subspace, but I think by these argument it should also hold true for general $Y$.

Comment: Technically Gram-Schmidt is an algorithm for producing an orthonormal basis on a finite-dimensional vector space, meaning it terminates after finitely many steps. I believe we need to invoke choice (or equivalently, Zorn's lemma) in order to make it work for infinite-dimensional spaces. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620667/gram-schmidt-in-hilbert-space

Comment: Separability does not mean that $Y$ has a countable **basis** (for instance, the algebraic dimension of a separable Hilbert space is either finite or $2^{\aleph_0}$). It certainly implies that any orthonormal subset of vectors is countable, though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think there is a version of Gram-Schmidt also for infinite dimensions (of course it's not exactly the same because as you said, it will not terminate after finitely many steps, but for an system of linearly independent $a_n$ we should find a system of orthonormal $b_n$ with $\overline{\text{lin}}\left\lbrace a_n \right\rbrace $ = $\overline{\text{lin}}\left\lbrace a_n \right\rbrace $).

Concerning the second comment, you're right, separability does not give us a countable basis, although I'm confused because for the case of a Hilbert-space I found on Wikipedia:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Separable_spaces, where it says "Along with Zorn's lemma, this means a Hilbert space is separable if and only if it admits a countable orthonormal basis."

Anyway, the arguments in my first post seem to be wrong, as we do not even have a Hilbert-space here. So I guess the statement I wanted to show is wrong... or are there other options to obtain the same result?

Comment: When you say "closure of the linear hull", do you mean the closure with respect to the topology of $X$ (in which case as David Ullrich says, this is impossible because $Y$ is not closed in $X$), or with respect to the subspace topology on $Y$ (in which case your reasoning is perfectly correct)?

Comment: @Gae.S.: It depends on what you mean by "basis".

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: In my case it appears to be indeed sufficient to take the closure wrt the topology of $Y$. Anyway, it's interesting to see how this can make the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is precisely that $Y$ is not a Hilbert space if it's not closed.

Note that $\overline{\text{lin}}S$ is closed by definition, so if $Y$ is not closed we cannot have $Y=\overline{\text{lin}}S$, hence $Y$ cannot have a basis by your definition.

Comment: It depends on whether the closure is meant to be taken in $X$, or in $Y$ with its subspace topology.  In the latter case everything works fine.